# What is the use of serialize method of Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, web-applications

Why exactly do we need `serialize` method. It appends data of form but so does `http get` then why do we need it?

```
The serialize() method creates a URL encoded text string by serializing form values.
```

Why should I use it. If I understand the proper usage of it, I will learn a better practice of using it in my forms.

Comment: used mostly as quick way to serialize form data for ajax

Answer (score 5):

The serialized values can be used in the URL query string when making an AJAX request.

info taken from [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serialize.asp)

Instead of using jQuery to grab all the values in your form then submitting to an external page, .serialize() will do it for you automatically. so in your external page, you can grab what you need through the URL and manipulate it as you please

example being:

you have a form like this:

```
<form action="#"  id="input_form">
    first name: <input type="text" name="first name" /><br />
    last name: <input type="text" name="last name" /><br />
    email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="send" name="submit" />
</form>
```

You can use an AJAX request like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#input_form").submit(function(){
        var first name = $('input[name=first name]').val();
        var last name = $('input[name=last name]').val();
        var email = $('input[name=email]').val();
        var querystring = "first name="+first name+"&last name="+last name+"&email="+email;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'elaboration.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: querystring,
            success: function(data) {
                //code to execute
                    }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Instead of doing this:

```
var first name = $('input[name=first name]').val();
var last name = $('input[name=last name]').val();
var email = $('input[name=email]').val();
var querystring = "first name="+first name+"&last name="+last name+"&email="+email;
```

You can do this instead using .serialize():

```
var querystring = $(this).serialize();
```

The `.serialize()` saves you some time and effort grabbing each value in your form essentially.

[Sauce](http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/how-and-when-to-use-jquerys-serialize-method/)

Comment: I still dont understand why will I use the above over 'get'

Comment: Instead of using jQuery to grab all the values in your form then submitting to an external page, .serialize() will do it for you automatically. so in your external page, you can grab what you need through the URL and manipulate it as you please.

Comment: or you can use it to post also

Comment: @AkiraDawson can you please elaborate? Instead of using jQuery to grab all the values in your form then submitting to an external page

Comment: @fscore I modified the answer for you, check it out, and where I referenced it from. He does talk a little bit about encoding the URL but that's for another time now haha

Comment: In what cases will I need to append values in the query string?

Comment: @fscore I was just thinking that myself, just off the top of my head, It'll be good for non-sensitive data such as, name, date etc. For more sensitive data such as passwords, credit card info, I wouldn't know to be honest. I don't know if jQuery offers some sort of encryption client side before sending it to the server, maybe use a secure link (https). I know server side code you can encrypt data and stash it in a database. But client side, I wouldn't know sorry.